# Run Command Whenever ANY Other Command is Run

Tags: unix, osx-yosemite, multitasking

I have a very unnecessary scripting question: how can I make the command `fortune` run along with any other command? So, for example, instead of running

```
something
```

I want to ALWAYS force run something *similar*, but not exactly

```
fortune && something
```

wherein the fortune command finishes before the other command begins.

Is there a way to do this in Mac OS X Yosemite?

Comment: It seems that the only avenue would be to modify your shell and create a special one, This shell could not be used to start the system for example.  Also note that && implies that the first  one succeeds.  This will also break all kinds of existing shell scripts. Ex:  grep 'foo' file | awk '{ print $1}'.  Horrible idea as presented.

Comment: What I would like isn't _exactly_ the && combination - just for the fortune command to be fired before (need to make an edit in there) the other command executes.

Comment: Well. please state EXACTLY what you are tryin do do - not how you think it could be done.

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is that the fortune command is run, then, after it finishes, it begins the actually fired command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve.
But you can try below:
eg. you want to fire 'hostname' and 'pwd' whenever 'hostname' command is fired.
Add below line in your bash profile.

```
alias hostname="hostname;pwd;"
```

you will get output like below:

```
[user@host ~] hostname
host1.example.com
/data/data2/new
```

Comment: This works for me! I only run a few commands anyways, so this method works perfectly.